# How count colors from png files without full decoding?

Tags: java, image, png, decode, encode

Consider following java code:

```
File file = ...

BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
int w = image.getWidth();
int h = image.getHeight();
int count = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        int pixel = image.getRGB(x, y);
        //count colors here
    }
}
```

Here what is happened in the code above:

1. Png bytes are from disk
2. Bytes decoded with png decoder
3. java image is constrcuted
4. Colors is counted

Can I skip step `3`? e.g. count bytes during decoding or better decode png image partially and store only color information. How to do that with java?

**Note**

As I spot, storing image with same dimention but different colors count leads to different size. For example photo can be 1000 bigger then same image but with one color (black for example). So **theoretically** it is possible to count image just read bytes without decode full image. Am I right? Or encoding algorithm do not support partially  decoding?

Comment: The 'encoding algorithm' is the well-known LZW. So (at least purely theoretically) it's possible to unpack the compressed parts in streaming mode and count the pixels as you read -- without storing the entire decompressed image. This needs memory for only 2 entire scan lines of the PNG image.

Comment: @Jongware is wrong on several points. PNG uses Flate compression, not LZW and because of the 2D filters used in PNG images, it's necessary to have at least most of a complete PNG codec to get to the actual pixel values. You can partially decode a PNG image, but you can't tell what color the pixels are until you've undone the filter. The "UP" filter references the previous (uncompressed) image line.

Comment: @BitBank: ah it was Flate, sorry. But about the filters -- that is precisely why I said you need *two* entire lines at minimum: the 'previous' and the 'current'.

Comment: There's just no way to tell the colors of all the pixels, without also fully decoding all the pixels. The only way you could save anything, was to count colors while decoding (and not store the pixels in memory). Unfortunately there is no such "streaming pixels" type decoder available for Java (as far as I know, please, please correct me if I'm wrong :-) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid the creation of the full image, you could use [PNGJ](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj/), a Java decoder library (disclaimer, my own) that allows to read the image progressively, row by row.

The main advantage would be less memory consumption (only relevant if the image is big), perhaps also speed. A further difference with respect to a higher level iamge abstraction as `BufferedImage` is that the library gives you the raw pixel values in the format used by the PNG, without mappings or transformations - depending on your scenario, this can be a plus or not.

Of course, you are still fully decoding the image, but there is no way of escaping this.